# Why do the sides of the Gaussian pillbox contribute nothing to the electric field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields

It says that the top and bottom of the pillbox contribute to the $E$ field but the sides don’t. I couldn’t quite understand this, please Help.

Comment: The electric field is parallel to those sides and so no field lines enter or leave those surfaces.

Comment: That works, thanks!

Comment: @Farcher That seems to be an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gaussian pillbox is used for infinite surface with surface charge density $\sigma$.

Now the point is **infinite surface with surface charge density $\sigma$**.

This suggests that Electric field vector is perpendicular to infinite surface and all Electric field vectors are parallel to each other.

When we take a small pillbox the sides are parallel to the electric field thus **Electric flux** through the sides is zero.

Why zero?

We know flux ($\Phi$) is given by: $$\Phi = \vec E \cdot A \cdot \hat n$$
where E is electric field,  A is area,  $\hat n$ is normal vector perpendicular to the surface.

[image]

We note that normal vector of side faces is perpendicular to the Electric Field vector thus dot product should be 0. $$\Phi_{side} = E \cdot A \cdot cos(\cfrac{\pi}{2})$$
$$\therefore \Phi_{side} = 0$$

Comment: Why is E perpendicular to the surface in the first place? If the surface is not a conductor, then E could have a component parallel to the surface. Edit: I suppose if we zoom in far enough - so that the surface becomes a plane, we can use a symmetry argument like here: [link] (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/122637/why-is-the-electric-field-of-an-infinite-insulated-plane-of-charge-perpendicular ). But this would work for any surface - not necessarily just infinite surfaces